# Facing issue in AWS glue, While trying Delta operations

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue, delta-lake

I am attempting to use the update/Delete/Upsert operation in Pyspark with AWS Glue.

I have instantiated spark with below configs:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension").config("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog").getOrCreate()
```

If I skip the update/Delete/Upsert operation, the merge, insert (which I assume also requires the DeltaSparkSessionExtension) works just fine. This makes no sense, why does the update operation throw this error but the merge operation does not?

I have tried to perform update and delete using direct transformation and also via spark-sql.

With direct transformation, i am facing the issue:

```
this delta operation required sparksession to be configured with glue
```

**Note: I have configured spark session with all the required Delta dependencies.**

With Spark-sql, I am using the following query:

```
MERGE INTO delta.`s3a://delta-lake-aws-glue-demo/current/` as superstore
USING delta.`s3a://delta-lake-aws-glue-demo/updates_delta/` as updates
ON superstore.row_id = updates.row_id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET *
WHEN NOT MATCHED
  THEN INSERT *
```

I am facing the below issue for the above query:

```
AnalysisException: Table does not support reads: delta.`s3a://delta-lake-aws-glue-demo/current/`
```

Tested out with following jars and the results are:

```
delta-core_2.11-0.6.1.jar -- deprecated jar
delta-core_2.12-0.8.0.jar -- jar which supports inserts and append.
delta-core_2.12-2.1.0.jar -- An error occurred while calling o103.save. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/SparkThrowable
delta-core_2.12-1.0.0.jar -- jar which supports inserts and append.
this delta operation required sparksession to be configured with glue
```

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks :)

Comment: Did you check this blog: https://dev.to/awscommunity-asean/making-your-data-lake-acid-compliant-using-aws-glue-and-delta-lake-gk9 (for glue 2.4) and https://dev.to/awscommunity-asean/sql-based-inserts-deletes-and-upserts-in-s3-using-aws-glue-3-0-and-delta-lake-42f0 (for glue 3.0).  I havent used / worked on delta lake package, so maybe please check these examples

Comment: Yes, gone through both the links and performed the same steps as they mentioned.  But facing issues with upserts and deletes.

Comment: What is the spark version ?

Comment: Tried with both Spark 2.4 and Spark 3.1.  Same issue :(

Comment: Any reason you need to use Glue? The MERGE query you posted here accesses the S3 locations directly, so it doesn't need to use Glue at all.

Comment: Just trying out POC on AWS Glue.  Since Glue is serverless, try out using it.